# Select data from one column and update another column based on condition

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a structure like this

```
Table LatestData
**Name        Version**
Name1       1.2  
Name2       1.4
Name3       1.6
Name4       1.3
Name5       2.2

Table CurrentData
Name        CurrentVersion   Compliance
Name1       1.0
Name3       0.7
Name4       1.2
```

I need to update the compliance column based on below conditions:
N=Latest version (version from LatestData table)

1. If currentVersion in CurrentData table is lessThan(N-2); Compliance = Full
2. If currentVersion in CurrentData table is in between greaterThan(N-2) and lessThan(N-4); Compliance = Partial
3. If currentVersion in CurrentData table is >N-5; Compliance = Not compliant

Can you please help me with query to update the Compliance colulmn for table CurrentData?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I don't really understand what you're after. Consider providing a properly representative example (including DDLs and/or a sqlfiddle) and together with the desired result set.

Comment: Updated the question. Somehow the greater than and less than signs got replaced by empty space. Based on the difference between the two version columns i need to update my compliance column. Till Now I am only able to fetch the data mapping to Names

Comment: and ... what is your problem? Do you know about CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END ???   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Thanks Alex, I don't have idea about CASE. I ll look into it. Can you please suggest with some sample query which can be close to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I wrote any SQL, but because you're requesting a sample query I thought that I'd give it a try. Maybe someone else can correct my answer if it turns out that it doesn't work as intended.

```
UPDATE CurrentData
JOIN LatestData on
    CurrentData.Name = LatestData.Name
SET Compilance = IF(CurrentVersion < Version - 2, 'FULL', IF(CurrentVersion > Version - 2 && CurrentVersion < Version - 4, 'Partial', IF(CurrentVersion > Version - 5, 'Not compilant', 'Nope')));
```

This has been tested and it should run fine =)

Comment: It surely helped, but not able to get it run as the join is not happening and the if else giving error

Comment: Ok, I rewrote it and and tested it. Now it should work as intended.

Comment: @SandiipPatil So, was it any helpful?